# Customizing the Visual Studio 2010 Toolbar - Open Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to customize the Standard Toolbar in VS2010 "Ultimate version" to add Open Project (on the File menu), but it's not available..

Steps:

**Tools** > **Customize...**

On the **Commands** Tab, select Toolbar, then **Standard** from the list

Click **Add Command...** button

Select **File** in the list

and no **Open Project** ???

Can't seem to find it anywhere else either.  Any idea, or how else to add it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have VS2010 Ultimate and also wasn't able to find this button to add on my install as well. I had my VS2010 setup to use the Web Settings.

I was able to add the button to my menu bar by switching my settings to the C# Development settings. I was then able to find the Open Project button by doing the following:

Right-click on a toolbar --> customize --> commands --> toolbar --> standard --> add command --> file --> 3 pages down in the list on the right: Open Project

I am not sure why this is not available when I was setup to use the Web Development Settings. This might be bug or possibly intentional. I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 1):

The button is unavailable also under Visual Basic Developer layout, probably it is accessible only under C# Developer layout (Tool / Import and Export Setting / Visual C# Development Setting). A possible solution for other layouts is the following macro command, which you then assing to a new toolbar button:

DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenProject")

I'm wondering, which functions are going to disappear in the next Visual Studio version :-(...

Answer (score 0):

It's there for me in VS2010 RTM:

Right-click on a toolbar --> customize --> commands --> toolbar -->
standard --> add command --> file --> 3 pages down in the list on the right: Open Project

Comment: No, missing for me. I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.  Which version do you have?

Comment: I have the same problem. I installed Visual Studio 2010 recently. I also have Visual Studio 2008. Maybe it's not there if you already have 2008 on your pc or maybe because you told it to use the Visual Basic settings like I did.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the SSIS (Data tools) version and I do have the option to add the Open Project button. It worked for me and now I have the toolbar customized with the button in it. R.